# Insert int into 2d vector at an certain position

Tags: c++, vector

So I am taking two values in an array at the same position on both arrays to add them together then putting those numbers into a new array at the same position. I know my addition part is working because I am returning an int at the point they are added however it for some reason will not add them together. Maybe I am using the correct syntax I'm not quite sure.

```
//Iterate Through Vector
for(int i = 0; i < FirstMatrixRows; i++)
                {
                    for(int z = 0; z < FirstMatrixColumns; z++)
                    {
                        //ADD VECTOR NUMBERS TOGHETHER
                        int VectorNum = FirstMatrix[i][z] + SecondMatrix[i][z];

                        //ADD ADDED NUMBER TO ARRAY AT SAME POSITION
                        FinalMatrix[i][z] = VectorNum;
                    }
                    
                }
```

EXAMPLE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> FirstMatrix;
    vector<vector<int>> SecondMatrix;
    vector<vector<int>> FinalMatrix;
    
    FirstMatrix = 
    {
        {2, 3} ,
        {3, 1}
    };
    SecondMatrix =
    {
        {2, 3} ,
        {3, 1} 
    };
            
    //Iterate Through Vector
    for(int i = 0; i < FirstMatrix[0].size(); i++)
                    {
                        for(int z = 0; z < FirstMatrix.size(); z++)
                        {
                            //ADD VECTOR NUMBERS TOGHETHER
                            int VectorNum = FirstMatrix[i][z] + SecondMatrix[i][z];
    
                            //ADD ADDED NUMBER TO ARRAY AT SAME POSITION
                            FinalMatrix[i][z] = VectorNum;
                        }
                    }
    return 0;
}
```

This Should return a vector that looks like:

```
    { 4, 6 }
    { 6, 2 }
```

Comment: Post a [mcve]. There is near-nothing to go on here.

Comment: Please also add an example of input/output.

Comment: Added an example will add example of input aswell/ output

Comment: How big do you think your `FinalMatrix` is going into that set of loops?

Comment: I think my FinalMatrix is going 4 values the same size as the other vectors.

Comment: That's what you *want* it to be. But what actually *is* `FinalMatrix` as you enter the loop? Ans: It's just an empty vector of vectors. It has no elements. `FinalMatrix[i][z] = VectorNum;` , therefore, invokes *undefined behavior*, not once, but twice (referring to a row that doesn't exist, and a column is said row that obviously also doesn't exist). It doesn't magically add a new row vector, and a new element within that row vector.

Comment: So would I have to set the vector to a certain size before I would be able to add to it. What would be the correct approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could implement matrix addition in C++20.

First write a lambda that adds the contents of 2 rows:

```
auto add_row = [](auto first, auto const &second)
{
    std::ranges::transform(first, second, first.begin(), std::plus{});
    return first;
};
```

Then use that lambda to add all the rows of the matrix:

```
std::ranges::transform(FirstMatrix, SecondMatrix, std::back_inserter(FinalMatrix), add_row);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7WTsrW).